# Discrepancy between Nvidia-smi Memory Usage and PyTorch Memory Reporting on GPU

Tags: memory, pytorch, gpu, nvidia-smi

I'm encountering a discrepancy between the memory utilization reported by nvidia-smi and what PyTorch is reporting when using GPU memory. For example, the following code snippet will print 2MB:

```
tensor = torch.randn(256, 256, device='cuda', dtype=torch.float16) 
snapshot = torch.cuda.memory._snapshot()
total_size = snapshot['segments'][0]["total_size"] / 1024 / 1024
print(total_size,"MiB")
```

Which is expected, since according to torch documentation,the smallest memory chunk that torch requests is 2MiB

However, when checking nvidia-smi:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.125.06   Driver Version: 525.125.06   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:41:00.0 Off |                  Off |
|  0%   34C    P8    14W / 450W |    391MiB / 24564MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
```

It appears that 391 MiB have been already used. Where is this mismatch coming from?

Comment: The GPU isn't just used by PyTorch, the OS and other programs running on it also need it to display stuff. Idk if SMI can filter that out, but that'd be my guess.

Comment: Torch was the only program running in this example. By the way, I did a bit of research, and it very likely it's the CUDA Context of Torch reserving ~390MB of memory.